# Mergesort doesn't work

Tags: c, mergesort

been trying for hours to find what is wrong with this code, and all of the mergesort's algorithms i've been googled looked  pretty much the same, this one doesnt work;
trying to do mergesort to a pointers-array:

output:
 2| 2| 3| 3| 4| 5| 4| 4| 7| 7|

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void merge( int ** pointerArray, int pivot,int size){
int leftSize=pivot;
int rightSize=size;
 int leftIndex=0, rightIndex=pivot, newIndex=0;

int **tempArray= (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*size);

while (leftIndex < leftSize && rightIndex < rightSize) {//merging two sorted array

    if ((*pointerArray)[leftIndex]<=(*pointerArray)[rightIndex] )
        (tempArray)[newIndex++]=(pointerArray)[leftIndex++];
    else
        (tempArray)[newIndex++]=(pointerArray)[rightIndex++];



}

while (leftIndex<leftSize )//rest of left array
    (tempArray)[newIndex++]=(pointerArray)[leftIndex++];

while (rightIndex<rightSize)//rest of right array
    (tempArray)[newIndex++]=(pointerArray)[rightIndex++];


    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)//copying the tempArray to the original array
    pointerArray[i]=tempArray[i];


free(tempArray);

}
void mergeSort( int ** ptrarray, int size){
if (size==1)
    return;
int pivot=size/2;
mergeSort(ptrarray, pivot);
mergeSort(ptrarray+pivot, size-pivot);
merge(ptrarray, pivot, size);



}

int** pointerSort(int* arr, unsigned int size,
              char ascend_flag)
{
int **pointerArray= (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*size);

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    pointerArray[i]=&arr[i];

mergeSort(pointerArray, size);

return pointerArray;
}

int  main()
{
int size=10;
int array[10]={3,2,3,5,4,7,2,7,4,4};
char ascend_flag =1;
int ** pointer= pointerSort(array, size, ascend_flag);

for (int **p=pointer; p-pointer<size; p++)//print sorted array
    printf(" %d|", *(*p));


}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged your code?

Comment: there was only one iteration that the merge function was comparing one of the number 7 to 1710702629 (garbage value i guess)    pointerArray[1] <= pointerArray[4]. I dont know why, i tried making sure that i am splitting the array correctly, and it was all fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not clear why you're sorting arrays of pointers-to-ints instead of just copying the ints themselves, it's definitely leading you astray. When you say:

```
if ((*pointerArray)[leftIndex] <= (*pointerArray)[rightIndex])
```

you're not comparing what you intend to.

`*pointerArray` is the same as `pointerArray[0]`, or the `int *` that's first in the list. You're comparing `pointerArray[0][leftIndex]` to `pointerArray[0][rightIndex]`, when what you *want* is effectively `pointerArray[leftIndex][0]` and `pointerArray[rightIndex][0]`, like so:

```
if (*(pointerArray[leftIndex]) <= *(pointerArray[rightIndex]))
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/Kgl3oO

*p.s.* The fact that the array appears kind-of-sorted in your version is a happy accident. Try it with a more mixed-up initial array, such as:

```
int array[10] = {97, 4, 2, 107, 6, 7, 14, 22, 89, 6};
```

and you'll see results like

```
4| 97| 7| 14| 22| 6| 2| 6| 107| 89|
```